# Can any type of conic section always be constructed around an isosceles trapezoid, such that it intersects all of the vertices?

Tags: geometry

I know that one can always construct a circle intersecting the vertices of an isosceles trapezoid. Can this be extended to other types of conic section?

Comment: What exactly do you call "around" ? You must be specific.

Comment: A conic section which intersects all of the vertices.

Answer (score 1):

A conic can be defined by five arbitrary points. Taking the four corners of the trapezoid, you have one degree of freedom left, which allows you to switch the type. This also works with a general quadrilateral.